# How to map numerical/alphabetical ranges in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I want to map numerical range in my Vim script. For example this doesn't work :-

```
inoremap {0-9}-{0-9} {0-9}<Space>-<Space>{0-9}
```

I am looking for the following behaviour :-

```
//Before mapping
  x=x-1;
  return -1;
//After mapping
  x = x - 1;
  return -1;
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but you can't map a range like that. This will map the literal text `{0-9}-{0-9}` to `{0-9} - {0-9}`

Comment: How can I map a range ? Are there any Vim notations ?

Comment: That's my point, you can't map a range in vim. You can probably get the same functionality some other way, but you'll need to describe exactly what you're trying to do. You should [edit] your question and carefully explain exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: Please check now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in range(0, 9)
    execute "inoremap " . n . "-" . n . " " . n . " - " . n
endfor
```

This loops over a list of numbers from `0` to `9` and creates a separate mapping for each number.

```
:help :for
:help range()
:help :execute
```

But I would try to improve my typing rather than rely on workarounds.

Comment: This only works for same digits. The following works though.                            `for a in range(0, 9)
    for b in range(0, 9)
 execute "inoremap " . a . "-" . b . " " . a . " - " . b
    endfor
endfor`